# How can a stream be used to calculate the sum of an array that receives input?

Tags: java, input, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I am new to programming with arrays, so I am not sure how I can calculate the sum of an array that receives input. Through research, I've learned how to set up an array and how to calculate the sum of the array using stream, but when the array receives input (such that it does not start with a set value), I do not know how to calculate the sum. Here is my code:

```
public class TestClass {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        double b = sc.nextDouble();
        a.add(b);
        int[] c = a;//This step is where I get lost. I'm not sure what needs to happen to a
        Arrays.stream(c);
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(c).sum());
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Note: java.util.*, java.io.*, java.util.stream.*, and java.util.Arrays are all imported.

Comment: You can use `a.stream.sum()` directly.  No need to convert to array.

Comment: @Kieran: you can *accept* only one answer. Once you have enough reputation, you may additionally *upvote* multiple answers…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` in conjunction with `Double::sum`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

List<Double> arr = new ArrayList<>(); // Use generics - never use raw types!
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    Double b = sc.nextDouble();
    arr.add(b);
    sc.nextLine(); // <-- add this line in order to be able to feed numbers manually
}
Double res = arr.stream().reduce(Double::sum).get();
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: You should specify to OP that you changed  the `List` declaration to indicate the  type `Double` else he may not realize and encounter incompatible types error.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I added some math functions, and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You think think about your task first. You are asking the scanner for `double` values and at a later time you want an `int[]` array. This doesn’t match.

As said by others, there is no need for an array, if you want to sum up the values as `double`, declare the list as `List<Double>` to clarify this. Then you can simply stream the list to sum it up like `list.stream().reduce(Double::sum).orElse(0)` or `list.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum()`.

However, if you are only interested in the sum, there is no need for a list at all:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    sum += sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

has the same effect. It doesn’t use a `Stream` but there wouldn’t be any benefit from using streams.

If you want to solve the task “sum up twenty input values” via `Stream` you may consider omitting the intermediate sums. In that case, there is a clean solution:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double sum=DoubleStream.generate(sc::nextDouble).limit(20).sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variation of the theme presented by [alfasin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057429/alfasin), you can specialise the `Stream` as a [`DoubleStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) and utilise the [`sum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--) method on it.

```
List<Double> arr = new ArrayList<>();
... enrol the numbers ...

double sum = arr.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).sum();
```

As mentioned by [Jean-François Savard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683146/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-savard), you should be aware that that your original `List` has been changed to `List<Double>` in this solution.  If you want to know why, read up on [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).